# The pyramids are in Egypt, not Kansas

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tour

For some reason, on the About page (https://stackexchange.com/about) the Pyramids are shown to be in Kansas. This is patently wrong, they are in Egypt. My findings are detailed below.

[image]

Comment: Those are the Rocky Montains, as Isaac Moses answered. Helps if you actually read the blurb next to the images ("Stack Exchange currently employs more than 200 people in its head offices in New York, Denver, and London").

Comment: Presumably this is less bydesign and more norepro

Comment: @Lightness - the location on the map is by-design. The idea that those are the pyramids - that's a no-repro ;)

Comment: That's not Kansas; Kansas is further east.

Comment: @Oded: exactly :D

Answer (score 11):

Those are presumably Rocky Mountains, emblematic of nearby Denver (the location in that vicinity mentioned on that page), not pyramids, and not in Kansas.

Comment: ...but also note that Denver is really only *near* the mountains. Denver isn't "in" the mountains, nor are there any mountains "in" Denver. In fact, Denver is actually at fairly low altitude (says the guy whose house at at ~7000 feet).

Comment: However, it _is_ one of the highest cities in the USA, being a mile above sea level. And that ain't nothin'.

Comment: Anyway, more to the point, the mountains are not "in" Denver.

Comment: @JerryCoffin as someone currently in Downtown Denver... the view of mount Evans is quite nice

Comment: @Mgetz: Call me biased if you will, but I prefer Pikes Peak. :-)